# Distribution of summation in RSS derivation

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, regression

I am learning how to derive the RSS formula and there is a step that is not making sense to me:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)   +   \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n   \bar x(y_i+\hat \beta x_i)}_{Q} - \underbrace{ \sum_{i=1}^n \bar x(\bar y-\hat\beta \bar x)}_M-\hat \beta \sum _{i=1}^n(\bar x-x_i)^2$
2. $Q=n\bar x\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-\hat \beta \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigg)=n\bar x(\bar y-\hat \beta \bar x)=M$

And for this reason, Q and M cancel out. My question is that I do not understand step 2. I  don't understand how distributing the summation term in the beginning, turns the inside components into "bar" terms...

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a typo, and $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x}(y_i-\hat{\beta}x_i) $ in step 1.

From there, note that $\bar{x}$ is a constant, so it can be factored out of the sum:

$$ Q = \bar{x} \sum_{i=1}^n{(y_i+ \hat{\beta}x_i)} .$$

Then, we split the summation into two separate sums:

$$ Q = \bar{x} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n{y_i} + \sum_{i=1}^n {\hat{\beta}x_i} \right).$$

Then, the same thing happens with $\hat{\beta}$ since it's a constant too:

$$ Q = \bar{x} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n{y_i} - \hat{\beta}\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i} \right).$$

The final step comes from the fact that $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i {x_i} \Longrightarrow n\bar{x} = \sum_i {x_i}$:

$$ Q = \bar{x} \left( n\bar{y} - \hat{\beta}n\bar{x} \right).$$

$$ \Rightarrow Q = n\bar{x} \left( \bar{y} - \hat{\beta}\bar{x} \right).$$

Comment: thank you! so to see if I understand, the summation "hops over" the $\bar x$ and is distributed within the summation. After this, one is left with $\bar x\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-\hat \beta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigg)$, and then, both terms are multiplied by "1", by multiplying them by $n\cdot \frac{1}{n}$, which converts the terms inside the parenthesis to $n\cdot\text{bar terms}$, and then the n that is a coefficient to both bar terms inside the parenthesis, is factored out to "join" the $\bar x $, and voila?

Comment: Yep. And the sum isn't really hopping, it's even simpler than that. If you write out your sum (using $a_i = y_i - \hat{\beta}x_i$), it's $\sum_i^n \bar{x}a_i = \bar{x}a_1 + \bar{x}a_2 + ... + \bar{x}a_n = \bar{x} *(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)$. It's as simple as $ab + ac = a(b+c)$, it just looks a little fancier.